# Selected Records in SQL Server Were Placed In Wrong Columns

Tags: sql-server

I have used a **select** statement in SQL Server which generated records with 5 columns.

[image: Database Result]

As you can see in record 4, the product that had a very long data was inserted in the wrong column. Why did this happen? I am using SQL Server 2012 by the way. TIA!

Comment: The SELECT statement didn't place it in the wrong column, the data is in the wrong column from how it was inserted into the table. Something is wrong, but we don't have enough information to guess at what it might be. At the very least you should share your SELECT statement, but again, it's probably the insertion of this data (and the script used to do that) that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you pasting the results into Excel?  If so, I suspect a CRLF in your long text.

Consider the following

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Descr varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'Some Short Desc'),
(2,'Some Long Desc with a CRLF
Some more text on the second line'),
(3,'Some Short text')

Select * from @YourTable
```

In SSMS it looks like this

[image]

If pasted into excel, you will see

[image]

One way to correct this is to strip CHAR(13) and CHAR(10)

```
Select ID,Descr=replace(replace(Descr,char(13),''),char(10),'') from @YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the full information so I'm assuming Sql Server is showing 4 records but when you copy these records into excel then there are 5 records like the picture which you have shared.

Solution to this problem is you have to remove the new line character and line feed from the product column.

Use below query:

```
SELECT ID, Title, REPLACE(REPLACE(product, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), country, isActive from YourTableName
```